# Determining the locale of a worker that has completed a HIT

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have created a HIT on Mechanical Turk and I need fluent English speakers to work on it. I have set the locale requirements to several English speaking countries (USA, Canada, UK, etc.), but I'm getting results with varying quality. Is there a way to know the locale of a worker that has submitted a HIT? I would like to know if there is any correlation between the quality of the result and the locale of the worker so that I could narrow down the requirements to the locale that provides higher quality submissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using only US which has a much higher quality than countries like India.

Or you can use Turkprime.com which has additional quality controls and a qualification for native English speaker on MTurk